# RDkit parse zero-order bonds (python)

Tags: python, rdkit, smiles

I'm a computer scientist, helping with a chemistry project in python.

I have been working with the library `pysmiles` in order to parse `SMILES` into a molecule graph, and that worked fine until now. Recently, I started changing code so it will work with `RDkit` as well, since the `RDkit` library is much larger and has many other useful features.

However, I noticed that `RDkit` doesn't create a bond for a molecule that has a "zero-order bond", unlike `pysmiles` which just puts the "zero-order-bond" as a data on that edge.

For technical reasons, I would like `RDkit` to do the same as `pysmiles`, and *do* create a bond, writing in it that it is a "zero-order bond".

As an example, the following molecule was generated by `RDkit`:

[image]

I want the $\ce{Cl-}$ to have an edge to the $\ce{N}$, that will have the data written on it that it is a zero order bond (any other node besides $\ce{N}$ would work as well, for as long as the process of choosing that node is deterministic and depends only on the molecule).

How can I do this? I didn't manage to find an answer in their documentation. Thanks!

---

As a side note, any technical way of making the molecule graph connected (in a way that doesn't depend on the particular `SMILES` string for a certain molecule) will suffice for me.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Note, *chemical* information may be advantageously formatted using on ChemSE with [mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/). Take moment to familiarize with this. You are encouraged to use it in the body of questions, answers, and comments. Because it is something special not all web browsers understand well, *do not* use it in the title of questions or answers.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Glad to know it exists :)

Comment: Chemically speaking, there is no covalent bond between the $\ce{Cl-}$ and *any* of the nitrogen atoms. To draw a line between $\ce{Cl-}$ and the nitrogen *in the center* ring would contradict that all valences (like «all hands available») are already engaged with the adjacent atoms (here: carbon). *Possibly* $\ce{Cl-}$ is somewhat close to the exocyclic $\ce{N+}$, because opposite charges attract each other.  What may be a reasonable option to retain both the organic cation and the anionic anion is to *concatenate* the SMILES strings of each by the period / full stop (as e.g., in co-crystals).

Comment: (continued)  In the present case, one possible SMILES string about both entities *altogether* were `CN(C)C1=CC=C2C(SC(C3=N2)=C/C(C=C3)=[N+](C)/C)=C1.[Cl-]`.  If you like to account for aromaticity of the rings, this equally may be expressed as `CN(C)c1ccc2c(sc3-c(n2)cc/c(=[N+](/C)\C)/c3)c1.[Cl-]`, too.

Comment: @Buttonwood I need some technical way to make the graph connected, in a deterministic process from the `SMILES` string, hopefully in a way that doesn't depend on which `SMILES` string we use to represent the same molecule

Comment: *If well explained to the audience eventually reading the graphs*, one possibly can borrow RDKit's approach to display *dative bonds* typically seen for organometallic complexes. Then, dashes are substituted by small arrows point from e.g., anions (like $\ce{Cl-}$) / Lewis bases toward the positively charged ion (normally a metal like platin) / Lewis acids, here $\ce{N+}$. While mechanically possible, it would require a note in advance to calm the readers.  RDKit's cookbook has an entry `->` and `<-` [here](https://www.rdkit.org/docs/Cookbook.html#organometallics-with-dative-bonds).

Comment: @Buttonwood thanks. However, the purpose is purely technical. Nobody is going to *actually look at the molecule*. The example I placed is the first such example from my dataset, that contains a total of around 10 thousand molecules

Comment: Nice to see some discussion going on here! After a certain point, the system will ask you to move it to chat, since comments aren't meant for extended discussion. Our [Phonopy chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112358/phonopy) has been a bit silent recently, so maybe we can turn it into the "Python software" room!